# "We usually grow vegetables in our garden" - Is this sentence correct?

Tags: tense, past-simple, present-simple

> We usually grow vegetables in our garden, but this year we are not growing any.

I saw this in a grammar exercise. I am curious why do they use "grow" instead of "grew".

Comment: Using "usually" removes any time constraint, so while the action likely occurred in the past, it could possibly occur in the present or future.

Answer (score 2):

They use the present simple tense ("grow") because the tense is used to talk about actions that repeat regularly (or usually, sometimes, often, seldom, rarely, etc.) or about permanent states.

"Grew" is past simple and would not really match the context and contrast set by the "but" and the sentence that follows it.

The contrast is that this year it's different than all the other years -- we've broken our habit.